# SimpleXML vs DOMDocument performance

Tags: php, performance, rss, simplexml, domdocument

I am building an RSS parser using the SimpleXML Class and I was wondering if using the DOMDocument class would improve the speed of the parser. I am parsing an rss document that is at least 1000 lines and I use almost all of the data from those 1000 lines. I am looking for the method that will take the least time to complete.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`SimpleXML` and `DOMDocument` both use the same parser (`libxml2`), so the *parsing* difference between them is negligible.

This is easy to verify:

```
function time_load_dd($xml, $reps) {
    // discard first run to prime caches
    for ($i=0; $i < 5; ++$i) { 
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($xml);
    }
    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($i=0; $i < $reps; ++$i) { 
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($xml);
    }
    $stop = microtime(true) - $start;
    return $stop;
}
function time_load_sxe($xml, $reps) {
    for ($i=0; $i < 5; ++$i) { 
        $sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    }
    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($i=0; $i < $reps; ++$i) { 
        $sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    }
    $stop = microtime(true) - $start;
    return $stop;
}


function main() {
    // This is a 1800-line atom feed of some complexity.
    $url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/reason/AllArticles';
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    $reps = 10000;
    $methods = array('time_load_dd','time_load_sxe');
    echo "Time to complete $reps reps:\n";
    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        echo $method,": ",$method($xml,$reps), "\n";
    }
}
main();
```

On my machine I get basically no difference:

```
Time to complete 10000 reps:
time_load_dd: 17.725028991699
time_load_sxe: 17.416455984116
```

The real issue here is what algorithms you are using and what you are doing with the data. 1000 lines is not a big XML document. Your slowdown will not be in memory usage or parsing speed but in your application logic.

Comment: I'd also add that not only *parsing* is the same, but most common tasks offer just about the same performance too. If your application is slow with one, it will be slow with the other.

Comment: Thanks that was a very good demonstration. I just have one more question. What if I only want to get the value of one tag from the feed. Which one would be faster or are the time differences insignificant as above? Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are benchmarking. (For one, DOM/SXE don't have "tags"!) There are multiple ways to get an element--by traversal or by XPath, and with XPath there are multiple equivalent XPaths which would perform differently. Why don't you benchmark? More importantly, have you even *encountered* a need for optimization? Most likely you don't need to worry about speed at all and are micro-optimizing prematurely.

Comment: I have done some benchmarking on my own program and it takes upwards of 25 secconds to complete because of the amount of data i am parsing. I am looking for the most performance because this script will be running fairly often. The reason i asked this question in the first place is because i havnt been using these objects for very long and i just picked simplexml because it was well, simple. I was just wondering if there were any performance/coding advantages to one or the other. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: You should find out what the bottleneck is by profiling. Parsing is not the bottleneck. You should either improve your algorithm or look for ways to run parts of your script in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have encountered a HUGE performance difference between `DomDocument` and `SimpleXML`. I have ~ 15 MB big XML file with approx 50 000 elements like this:

```
...
<ITEM>
  <Product>some product code</Product>
  <Param>123</Param>
  <TextValue>few words</TextValue>
</ITEM>
...
```

I only need to "read" those values and save them in PHP array. At first I tried `DomDocument` ...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $external_content );
$root = $dom->documentElement; 

$xml_param_values = $root->getElementsByTagName('ITEM');
foreach ($xml_param_values as $item) {
    $product_code = $item->getElementsByTagName('Product')->item(0)->textContent;
    // ... some other operation
}
```

That script died after 60 seconds with *maximum execution time exceeded* error. Only 15 000 items of 50k were parsed.

So I rewrote the code to `SimpleXML` version:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($external_content);
foreach($xml->xpath('ITEM') as $item) {
    $product_code = (string) $item->Product;
    // ... some other operation
}
```

After **1 second** all was done.

I don't know how those functions are internally implemented in PHP, but in my application (and with my XML structure) there is really, REALLY HUGE performance difference between `DomDocument` and `SimpleXML`.

Comment: There is a huge difference in using xpath and just getting elements by their tag. Judging by how those scripts behave, xpath function actually does not recover all the elements at once, providing you with an iterator object instead - which will be significantly lighter and faster.

It's the same as with loading files - you can load a huge file at once or read every line. Since reading every line does not require loading everything into memory at once, it will perform better.

Comment: The above comment is correct, its not about DomDocument vs SimpleXML, its about how you iterate. Changing the iteration on the DomDocument from getElementsByTagName to DOMXPath instead, makes it just as fast. My tests on a ~120.000 elements document confirms this