# PHP: Get feed content of the past hour

Tags: php, rss

I want to get the content of an external RSS feed and store entries from the **last hour only**.

So, I can get the RSS feed by:

```
$url = 'http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/all/rss.xml';
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load($url);

$print_r($feed); // display content...
```

Now, `$feed` contains **all** the data of the RSS feed. I want to store links to entries posted in the past hour only:

```
$latest_posts = array(
   $URL_1,
   $URL_2,
   $URL_3,
   $URL_4,
   //...
);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points once it becomes eligible.

Comment: unless the feed url provides filtering options, you'll have to accept that you're downloading ALL of the feed's urls, and then you can filter them out in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to loop through the feed and check the pubDate

```
//Loop through all the items
foreach ($feed->getElementsByTagName("item") as $item){
   //get the pubDate of the time, and compare it to time (obviously for the 1 hour ago you could do time() - 3600, but for the interest of self-documenting code in this example I've used strtotime()
   if (strtotime($item->getElementsByTagName("pubDate")->item(0)->nodeValue) >= strtotime("-1 hour")){
        //If it is, add it to the array...
        $latest_posts[] = $item->getElementsByTagName("link")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    } else {
        break; //If this post is more than 1 hour old, then so will the rest of them be, so break out of the loop.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['... on line if (strtotime($item... But can't seem to locate the error, can you?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? I've used a 5.4 feature that allows you to access a particular index of a method return, but if you are using 5.3, that won't work - having siad that, 5.3 is no longer supported, so if that's the case, please upgrade!!

Comment: replace pubDate to lastBuildDate, as shown in the external url

Comment: @FahedAlkaabi - why would you do that?? lastBuildDate is applicable to the whole feed, but the OP wants the specific items that have been posted in the last hour, skipping ones that are older - lastBuildDate doesn't apply at a per-item level.

Comment: My apologies, I am an idiot, I was running 5.3 -- I am now testing it on php 5.5 and receiving the following error on the same line: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: Apologies, I don't work with DOMDocument much (read: ever) - will update the answer now to use their method :-)

Comment: Lovely, works fine. I'll bounty this badboy with 50 points in 2 days when eligible!

Comment: Given that this will be bountied and for completion, can you please edit your answer to add a break in the loop? I would do this for you but I don't have enough reputation to do it without review...

Answer (score 1):

Simple convert xml to array 
[Demo](http://so.devilmaycode.it/get-rss-feed-into-php-array-possible/index.php)

you can use this code to convert it

```
$feed = 'http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/all/rss.xml';
$feed_to_array = (array) simplexml_load_file($feed);
//OR $feed_to_array = (array) new SimpleXmlElement( file_get_contents($feed) );
// print_r($feed_to_array); // if you want see the array

$feeds_i_need = array();
foreach($feed_to_array['channel']['item'] as $item) {
    if (strtotime($item['pubDate'] >= strtotime("-1 hour")))
         $feeds_i_need[] = $item;
    else
         break; // I did break so it will stop loop for others
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although is this approach any better than the other one posted (in terms of performance...)?

Comment: Make sure the items are sorted by pubDate, if not please remove **break;**

Comment: @HenrikPetterson - DOMDocument and simpleXML use the same parser underneath, so the performance difference there is minor - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367069/simplexml-vs-domdocument-performance 

Converting the simplexml object to an array will probably be a little slower, but Fahed makes a good point in that, if you know your RSS feed items are in date order, once you do get beyond 1 hour you could break out of the loop to avoid checking the rest of the items.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson - both way is good on performance, but DOMDocument does read all content and do loop few time to get the result, simpleXML also does few loops but you can control it as I did in break

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I should note that I am getting an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$feeds_i_need' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: There is a syntax error - should be a closing bracket on the first strtotime function:
 if (strtotime($item['pubDate'] __)__ >= strtotime("-1 hour"))

Comment: @HenrikPetterson - I did the fix if (strtotime($item['pubDate'] >= strtotime("-1 hour")))

Answer (score 1):

This is my first post. I hope this help you.

I couldn't fetch the xml with de load function. I think this is more simple.

Sorry for my english.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Buenos_Aires');
$url = 'http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/all/rss.xml';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$now = new DateTime('Tue, 01 Dec 2015 11:57:02 -0500');<--set your current date time.
$last_hour_feeds = array();
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
    $itemPubDate = new DateTime($entry->pubDate);
    $difference = $now->diff($itemPubDate);//php version > 5.3
    /*  
   [y] => 0
   [m] => 0
   [d] => 6
   [h] => 20
   [i] => 17
   [s] => 2
   [weekday] => 0
   [weekday_behavior] => 0
   [first_last_day_of] => 0
   [invert] => 1
   [days] => 6
 */
    if (!$difference->days && !$difference->h && $difference->invert){
        $last_hour_feeds[] = $entry->link; 
    }   
}
print_r($last_hour_feeds);
```